# How Do I Nest Meteor Spacebars Templates?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm using a package called AutoForm.

```
{{> afQuickField name="propertyInfo.zipcode" placeholder="XXXXX" class="form-control track-order-change"}}
```

It basically renders a label and input element.

I have a session variable:

```
Session.set("zipcode", //something dynamic);
```

I have a registered helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("zipcode", function(){
  return Session.get("zipcode");
})
```

I would like something like this to work:

```
{{> afQuickField name="propertyInfo.zipcode" value="{{zipcode}}" placeholder="XXXXX" class="form-control track-order-change"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix you global helper to read:

```
Template.registerHelper("zipcodeHelper", function(){
  return Session.get("zipcode");
})
```

Then fix the afQuickField a little:

```
{{> afQuickField value=zipcodeHelper class="form-control track-order-change"}}
```

Refer to this GH issue: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/210